# How to auto arrange data from a chunk of data in excel

Tags: excel

Suppose I have this chunk of data

```
Rice 10, 40, 60, HF4, HF6, HF7, Water 20, 30, WR20, WR70, Milk 10, 20, 30, 50, TR90, TR21, TR33, TR80
```

The fields I want to have is Item, Units, Location. This is one full record from the above chunk:

```
Water 20, 30, WR20, WR70,
```

So, the structure I want for this data is like this:

```
Item     |    Units     |    Location
_____________________________________
Water    |      20      |       WR20
Water    |      30      |       WR70
```

The other data will be arranged accordingly. Note that, Water has 2 Units hence 2 locations, but Rice has 3 and Milk has 4. What I am trying to say is that there is no fixed pattern on how many different quantities there will be for an item.

So how do I attain this using excel can anyone help me please. Any solutions will be much appreciated.

Comment: It's fine that Item has multiple units/locations. But would Water always have 2, Rice 3, etc? Or is that variable as well?

Comment: its not fixed, and there will not be only 3 items, there will be many more, no fixed amount of items and no fixed amount of different quantities for each items. @M.L